# Обновить свойство экземпляра класса set{} не срабатывает C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый вечер. Имеется `Model` в которой располагаются свойства модели

public class Layer:LayerProperties
{

```
#region PropertyChangedEventHandler
/// <summary>
/// Метод проверяющий изменилось ли свойство
/// </summary>
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion

private string _nameLayer;
/// <summary>
/// свойство Имени слоя
/// </summary>
public string NameLayer
{
    get { return _nameLayer; }
    set
    {
        if((value!=null)&&(!CheckLayersName(value))&&(_nameLayer!="0"))
        {
            RenameLayer(_nameLayer, value);
            //LayerProcedure("Rename",this);
            _nameLayer = value;
        }
        if (_nameLayer == null)
        {
            _nameLayer = value;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // иначае вывести exeption который еще не реализован
    }
}

private bool _showLayer;
/// <summary>
/// Свойство видимости слоя
/// </summary>
public bool ShowLayer
{
    get { return _showLayer; }
    set
    {
        ChangeLayerVisibility(_nameLayer,value);
        _showLayer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }

 private string _colorLayer;
 /// <summary>
 /// Свойство цвета слоя
 /// </summary>
 public string ColorLayer
 {
     get { return _colorLayer; }
     set
     {
        ChangeLayerColor(_nameLayer, value);
        _colorLayer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }

 private ObservableCollection<IObject> _opjectsCollection;
/// <summary>
/// Свойство колекциии объектов
/// </summary>
 public ObservableCollection<IObject> ObjectsCollection
 {
     get { return _opjectsCollection; }
     set { _opjectsCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
 }
```

}

```
/// <summary>
/// Интерфес объектов слоя
/// </summary>
public interface IObject:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "");
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображает наименование типа объекта
    /// </summary>
    string NameObject { get; set; }

}

 public class CircleElement:ModelBase, IObject
    {
        #region variables
        private PointElement _point;
        private double _radius;
        private string _nameObject;
        #endregion

        public CircleElement(PointElement center, double radius)
        {
            Point = center;
            Radius = radius;
            Point.PropertyChanged += PointPropertyChanged;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Радиус
        /// </summary>
        public double Radius
        {
            get { return _radius; }
            set { _radius = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Координаты точки центра
        /// </summary>
        public PointElement Point
        {
            get { return _point; }
            set { _point = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private void PointPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(PointElement.Z))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Реализация отображения наименование типа объекта
        /// </summary>
        public string NameObject
        {
            get { return _nameObject; }
            set { _nameObject = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }
    }

public class PointElement:ModelBase,IObject
{
    private string _nameObject;
    private double _x;
    private double _y;
    private double _z;

    public PointElement(Point3d point3d)
    {
        X = point3d.X;
        Y = point3d.Y;
        Z = point3d.Z;
    }

    public PointElement(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double X { get { return _x; } set { _x = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public double Y { get { return _y; } set { _y = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public double Z { get { return _z; } set { _z = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Реализация отображения наименование типа объекта
    /// </summary>
    public string NameObject
    {
        get { return _nameObject; }
        set { _nameObject = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class ShowLayersViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        #region variables

        private ObservableCollection<Layer> _layersCollection;
        private Layer _selectedLayer;
        private IObject _selectedObjectInLayer;
        private IObject _selectedObjectInLayerOld;
        private BlockTableViewModel _blockTable;
        private LayerProperties _layerProperties = new LayerProperties();

        #endregion

        public ShowLayersViewModel()
        {
            //получаем коллекицю слоев
            _layersCollection = _layerProperties.ReadLayer();
            _layerProperties.ReadBloackTable(_layersCollection);

            //Обработчик нажатия кнопки на добавления нового слоя
            ClickCommandAddLayer = new Command(arg => { _layersCollection.Add(_layerProperties.AddLayer()); });
            //Обработчик нажатия кнопки на удаление выбранного слоя
            ClickCommandDeleterLayer = new Command(arg =>
            {
                if (_selectedLayer.DeleteLayer(SelectedLayer.NameLayer))
                {
                    _layersCollection.Remove(_selectedLayer);
                } //иначе exeption 
            });

            ClickCommandChangeObject = new Command(arg =>
            {
                _layerProperties.ChangeColorObject(SelectedObjectInLayer);
            });

            ClickCommandCancelChangeObject = new Command(arg =>
            {
                _layerProperties.ChangeColorObject(_selectedObjectInLayerOld);
            });

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство коллекции экзмепляров слоев
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Layer> LayersCollection
        {
            get { return _layersCollection; }
            set { _layersCollection = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство выбранного экземпляра
        /// </summary>
        public Layer SelectedLayer
        {
            get { return _selectedLayer; }
            set
            {
                _selectedLayer = value;
                value.PropertyChanged += Test;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ConvertIObjectInTypeElement _convertIObjectInTypeElement = new ConvertIObjectInTypeElement();

        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство выбранного объекта
        /// </summary>
        public IObject SelectedObjectInLayer
        {
            get { return _selectedObjectInLayer; }
            set
            { 
                _convertIObjectInTypeElement.ProcessingCommand(value.GetType().Name,value); 

                _selectedObjectInLayer = value; OnPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Свойсто добавления слоя
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ClickCommandAddLayer { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство удаления слоя
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ClickCommandDeleterLayer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство изменения параметра объекта
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ClickCommandChangeObject { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство отмены изменения параметра объекта
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ClickCommandCancelChangeObject { get; set; }
    }
```

При биндинге во View на координаты точки, при изменение координаты set{} в классе Layer не срабатывает, каким образом именно в этом классе можно словить изменение этого свойство экземпляра класса.

тут `DataGrid` со слоями и в строке

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Object.PointX, Model=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged">
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Object.PointY, Model=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged">
```

Примерно такой XAML тут при выборе строки открывается подстрока со списком, Object, в примере который описан выше не точен так как был написан вручную для краткости.

```
<DataGrid
            Name="Layers"
            Grid.Row="1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE4DDDD"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LayersCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLayer}"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding NameLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Название слоя" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding ShowLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Выкл" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" Header="Цвет">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Width="17"
                                Height="17"
                                Command="{view:ParentWindowBinding DataContext.ClickCommandVisibleInColorPickerUC}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Rectangle
                                                        Name="ColorLayer"
                                                        Width="17"
                                                        Height="17"
                                                        Fill="{Binding Path=ColorLayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                        Stroke="Black" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:BlockTable />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

UcerControl BlockTable

```
        <Style x:Key="VisibilityBorder">
            <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="{Binding ElementName=VisibleObjects, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource ShowDataGridToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ToggleButton
                    x:Name="VisibleObjects"
                    Height="18"
                    Background="DarkGray"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=VisibleObjects, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource ShowButtonToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </Border>

            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource VisibilityBorder}">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Children>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="EnabledObject"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommandChangeObject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                            Content="Редактировать" />
                        <Button
                            x:Name="CancelChange"
                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommandCancelChangeObject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                            Content="Отменить" />
                    </StackPanel.Children>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>


            <Border
                Width="100"
                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource VisibilityBorder}">
                <ListBox
                    x:Name="ObjListBox"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectsCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedObjectInLayer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameObject}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Border>

            <Border
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=AccessToEdit, Path=IsChecked}"
                Style="{StaticResource VisibilityBorder}">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ObjListBox, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource SelectedObjectBindingExtension}}">
                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type objects:CircleElement}">
                            <objectsUC:CircleUC />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type objects:LineElement}">
                            <objectsUC:LineUC />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type objects:PointElement}">
                            <objectsUC:PointUC />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: а покажите побольше Xaml

Comment: @СтаниславПечезеров Добавил, но выше код это краткая выдержка сути. может быть в XAML сейчас будет не совпадение типов так как во ViewModel реализованы коллекции и т.д.

Comment: У вас свойство называется `ObjectLayer`, а не `Object`, поэтому привязка не срабатывает

Comment: @Андрей говорю что писалось выше это пример, связи у меня норм работают. Проблема именно в  обновление данных в set основного  объекта

Comment: Приведите настоящий код, т.к в этом я проблем не вижу. Чудес не бывает, убедитесь, что привязка точно работает

Comment: @FoggyFinder: `public class Object:ModelBase`

Comment: @Андрей Вот привел почти весь коод

Comment: @Андрей по части работы с блоком Layer

Comment: @VladD Проблема то у меня заключалась в том что при Обновление свойства внутри экземпляра объекта надо было как то сам экземпляр обновить что бы в ветке в верху сработал Set или как то так.
т.е. у меня Есть класс СЛОИ в нем свойства public IObject Object {get;set;} но происходит изменение параметров класса пришедшего интерфейса (утрировано на самом деле там коллекция и элементы (круг точка и т.д. наследуют этот интерфейс)) при изменении свойства элемента хочу поймать наверху что бы можно было определить какой это элемент был изменен  и т.д.

Comment: Вы байндите к IObject, который реализует только одно свойство NameObject. Откуда там возьмутся свойства PointX и PointY?

Comment: @John когда выбирается определенный объект у меня он приводится к типу этого объекта, и с помощью SelectedInIObject.PropertyChenged += ObjectPropertyChanged; подписываюсь к изменениям

Comment: Вы говорите про SelectedObjectInLayer? Так он у вас тоже IObject и у него так же не может быть других свойств кроме NameObject. Провериться просто: создайте экземпляр вашего класса ShowLayersViewModel в коде и попробуйте получить в нем доступ к нужному свойству только через видимые свойства.